# Check if a file exists using a wildcard

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how can I check if a file exists using a wildcard?

Apparently this does not seem to work:

```
File.exists?("/folderOfFile/Filename*.ext")
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Your wildcard would refer to a set of files, not a single file.  You could use [`Dir::glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) for this:

```
!Dir.glob('/folderOfFile/Filename*.ext').empty?
```

Comment: ```![].empty? == [].any?``` :)

Comment: Or shorter: `Dir['whatever*'].any?`